# Text File Writing Not Working

Tags: java, output

I have been experimenting with writing to text files for output instead of `System.out.println()`. When I try this, though, nothing seems to be written. What is the issue with my code?

```
    try{
        List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("Data Goes Here");
        Path file = Paths.get("output.txt");
        Files.write(file, lines, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        }

    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Frick, something broke. Sorry folks, go home.");
        }
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with this example. Are you seeing `Frick, something broke. Sorry folks, go home` as output/console? If yes instead of logging that message print exception stacktrace via `ex.printStackTrace();` to get more info about cause of the problem.

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: What array are you passing to `Arrays.asList`? It might be empty. Try printing it in the console.

Comment: I can't seem to get anything at all, not even my `catch` line. I may have put files in the wrong place and messed up like that, but I doubt it.

Comment: Try to use full path for file name to be 100% sure where to find it

Comment: Are you sure that this `try{..}` block is executed? Maybe it is placed in some method which is not called at all. Or maybe it is in some `if` block which condition is never true.

Comment: Check the output.txt file is existing in your src folder. If not then do provide full path.

Answer (score -1):

I just did a small change to your code by passing the path as the resources directory located in the root of my project. I was able to write to the file successfully.

Here is the updated code:

```
    try {
        List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("Data Goes Here");
        Path file = Paths.get("./resources/test.txt");
        Files.write(file, lines, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }

    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Frick, something broke. Sorry folks, go home.");
    }
```

Comment: What happened before that change? Ware you able to reproduce OP problem?

Comment: it would be better if you can share cause and details with your solution instead of just writing the solution.